# How do I publish NuGet packages to GitHub Package Registry using dotnet on Mac?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-cli, github-package-registry

The documentation is not complete and currently I cannot consume or publish package to GPR using dotnet on Mac. Any help would be useful

Comment: I think it is not a 'Mac' issue but a 'dotnet' issue, regardless of the operative system, I can't confirm right now, as I don't have Windows machine around, consider changing the question title to 'using dotnet-cli' instead of 'dotnet on mac'

Answer (score 4):

Far from ideal, and I haven't tested on Mac yet, but it worked on Linux

### Publish

- Enable GPR 'feature' in your GitBHub settings
- Go to github and add a TOKEN with GPR read/write access
- Add source locally

  ```
  nuget source Add -Name "GitHub" \
    -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ACCOUNT/index.json"
  ```
- Set api key

  ```
  nuget setApiKey $TOKEN \
      -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ACCOUNT/index.json"
  ```

#### Push package

```
    nuget push "my.lib.nupkg" -Source "GitHub"
```

#### Install package

```
    nuget install my.lib -pre # '-pre' because of alpha, if alpha
```

```
Note:  
'nuget install' downloads the nuget package  
It doesn't add it to the project.  
'dotnet' can't find it  
Do it anyway so it gets cached in `~/.nuget/packages`
The `./project` relative downloaded package can be deleted
```

*Reference manually:*

Add 'new Source' to nuget.config.

`<add key="GitHub" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ACCOUNT/index.json" />`

nuget config can be

- './nuget.config'
- '~/.nuget/NuGet/nuget.config'

*Add to project*:

```
    dotnet add package my.lib \            
        -v 1.0.0-alpha \
        -n # don't download, it can't handle authentication
```

*Alternatively*:
Edit project package reference

`<PackageReference Include="my.lib" Version="1.0.0-alpha" />`

Finally:

```
dotnet restore
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see at this link [to the github community question](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/github-package-registry-not-compatible-with-dotnet-nuget-client/td-p/34776) dotnet nuget is currently not supported by the GPR and you rather have to use nuget with Mono or publish from Windows.

I hope they'll fix it in the near future myself, it's completely stopping me from taking advantage of the GPR.

Comment: Your post saved me from continuing to bang my head against the wall on a Linux machine. The understandable frustration is apparent in the thread you linked.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make the HTTP call yourself (other steps omitted for brevity):

```
jobs:
  continuous-integration:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: push
      run: |
        for f in ./packages/*.nupkg
        do
          curl -vX PUT -u "<YOUR USER NAME>:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" -F package=@$f https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<YOUR USER NAME>/
        done
      if: github.event_name == 'push'
```